# TypeError: classes are undefined ReactComponent. Material-kit-react

Tags: reactjs, react-redux, material-ui

I am trying to do a little example from material-kit, in own project, but I Can not make it work. The problem that I Have is in the render when I did

> const { classes, ...rest } = this.props;

Never works causes classes are undefined. Debugging I find that I haven't got my Object Header, then the function __objectWithStyles, never works because in this.props are not be the object Header.

Can someone help me?

My LoginPage.jsx

```
 import React from "react";
// material-ui components
import withStyles from "@material-ui/core/styles";
// core components
import Header from "components/Header/Header.jsx";
import HeaderLinks from "components/Header/HeaderLinks.jsx";    
import loginPageStyle from "assets/jss/material-kit-react/views/loginPage.jsx";

 class LoginPage extends React.Component {


 constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    // we use this to make the card to appear after the page has been rendered
    this.state = {
      cardAnimaton: "cardHidden"
    };
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    // we add a hidden class to the card and after 700 ms we delete it and the transition appears
    setTimeout(
      function() {
        this.setState({ cardAnimaton: "" });
      }.bind(this),
      700
    );
  }
  render() {
    const { classes, ...rest } = this.props;
    return (
      <div>
        <Header
          absolute
          color="transparent"
          brand="Material Kit React"
          rightLinks={<HeaderLinks />}
          {...rest}
        />
        <div
          className={classes.pageHeader}
          style={{
            backgroundImage: "url(" + image + ")",
            backgroundSize: "cover",
            backgroundPosition: "top center"
          }}
        >
    );
    }
```

export withStyles(loginPageStyle)(LoginPage);
        }

The HeaderPage.jsx

```
import React from "react";
// nodejs library that concatenates classes
import classNames from "classnames";
// nodejs library to set properties for components
import PropTypes from "prop-types";
// material-ui components
import withStyles from "material-ui/styles/withStyles";
import AppBar from "material-ui/AppBar";
import Toolbar from "material-ui/Toolbar";
import IconButton from "material-ui/IconButton";
import Button from "material-ui/Button";
import Hidden from "material-ui/Hidden";
import Drawer from "material-ui/Drawer";
// @material-ui/icons
import Menu from "@material-ui/icons/Menu";
// core components
import headerStyle from "assets/jss/material-kit-react/components/headerStyle.jsx";

class Header extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      mobileOpen: false
    };
    this.handleDrawerToggle = this.handleDrawerToggle.bind(this);
    this.headerColorChange = this.headerColorChange.bind(this);
  }
  handleDrawerToggle() {
    this.setState({ mobileOpen: !this.state.mobileOpen });
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    if (this.props.changeColorOnScroll) {
      window.addEventListener("scroll", this.headerColorChange);
    }
  }
  headerColorChange() {
    const { classes, color, changeColorOnScroll } = this.props;
    const windowsScrollTop = window.pageYOffset;
    if (windowsScrollTop > changeColorOnScroll.height) {
      document.body
        .getElementsByTagName("header")[0]
        .classList.remove(classes[color]);
      document.body
        .getElementsByTagName("header")[0]
        .classList.add(classes[changeColorOnScroll.color]);
    } else {
      document.body
        .getElementsByTagName("header")[0]
        .classList.add(classes[color]);
      document.body
        .getElementsByTagName("header")[0]
        .classList.remove(classes[changeColorOnScroll.color]);
    }
  }
  componentWillUnmount() {
    if (this.props.changeColorOnScroll) {
      window.removeEventListener("scroll", this.headerColorChange);
    }
  }
  render() {
    const {
      classes,
      color,
      rightLinks,
      leftLinks,
      brand,
      fixed,
      absolute
    } = this.props;
    const appBarClasses = classNames({
      [classes.appBar]: true,
      [classes[color]]: color,
      [classes.absolute]: absolute,
      [classes.fixed]: fixed
    });
    const brandComponent = (
      <Button href="#" className={classes.title}>
        {brand}
      </Button>
    );
    return (
      <AppBar className={appBarClasses}>
        <Toolbar className={classes.container}>
          {leftLinks !== undefined ? brandComponent : null}
          <div className={classes.flex}>
            {leftLinks !== undefined ? (
              <Hidden smDown implementation="css">
                {leftLinks}
              </Hidden>
            ) : (
              brandComponent
            )}
          </div>
          <Hidden smDown implementation="css">
            {rightLinks}
          </Hidden>
          <Hidden mdUp>
            <IconButton
              color="inherit"
              aria-label="open drawer"
              onClick={this.handleDrawerToggle}
            >
              <Menu />
            </IconButton>
          </Hidden>
        </Toolbar>
        <Hidden mdUp implementation="css">
          <Drawer
            variant="temporary"
            anchor={"right"}
            open={this.state.mobileOpen}
            classes={{
              paper: classes.drawerPaper
            }}
            onClose={this.handleDrawerToggle}
          >
            <div className={classes.appResponsive}>
              {leftLinks}
              {rightLinks}
            </div>
          </Drawer>
        </Hidden>
      </AppBar>
    );
  }
}

Header.defaultProp = {
  color: "white"
};

Header.propTypes = {
  classes: PropTypes.object.isRequired,
  color: PropTypes.oneOf([
    "primary",
    "info",
    "success",
    "warning",
    "danger",
    "transparent",
    "white",
    "rose",
    "dark"
  ]),
  rightLinks: PropTypes.node,
  leftLinks: PropTypes.node,
  brand: PropTypes.string,
  fixed: PropTypes.bool,
  absolute: PropTypes.bool,
  // this will cause the sidebar to change the color from
  // this.props.color (see above) to changeColorOnScroll.color
  // when the window.pageYOffset is heigher or equal to
  // changeColorOnScroll.height and then when it is smaller than
  // changeColorOnScroll.height change it back to
  // this.props.color (see above)
  changeColorOnScroll: PropTypes.shape({
    height: PropTypes.number.isRequired,
    color: PropTypes.oneOf([
      "primary",
      "info",
      "success",
      "warning",
      "danger",
      "transparent",
      "white",
      "rose",
      "dark"
    ]).isRequired
  })
};

export default withStyles(headerStyle)(Header);
```

There a link from the src repository: https://github.com/creativetimofficial/material-kit-react/

**Updated**

It seems that my class LoginPagte can not find the components that I import. For example.

> import Header from "components/Header/Header.jsx";

My class can not find **Header object**

Answer (score 3):

Maybe Im too late. But, I had the similiar problem. I did a little change and it started working fine.

Before: `import {Register} from "./Register/Register";`

After: `import Register from "./Register/Register";`

just removing "{}" from import of Register component in the root component worked for me. And yes of course you need: `export default withStyles(styles)(Register);`

Answer (score 0):

It means you didn't pass `classes` to your `LoginPage`. I guess you want it to wrapped with [`withStyles`](https://material-ui.com/customization/css-in-js/#api), which injects `classes` into component:

```
export withStyles(loginPageStyle)(LoginPage)
```

then use it where you are using `LoginPage`.

Comment: I Forgot to place into my sample.. i have it. But still not working... Edited in the post.

Answer (score -1):

Add `classes` as a prop of the component this way:

```
   class LoginPage extends React.Component<{ classes }, {}> {

        ...
    }
```

Comment: Not working, classes are undefined... I think is a problem with my imports. It seems that my class can't read the object that I imported.